# static link stdc++ without STB_GNU_UNIQUE cause memory leak when dlclose

Tags: dynamic, memory-leaks, static-linking, gold-linker

I have to make a dso that static link stdc++ and need can unload from memory dynamic. So I tried with compile gcc with `--disable-gnu-unique-object` and use gold link with `-Wl,--no-gnu-unique` options. But both contains memory leak issue even I do nothing except call `dlopen() dlclose()` in main. The test code like:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        void * h=dlopen(filepath);
        if(h)
             dlclose(h);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Than I checked the memory `cat /proc/pid/maps` before and after I found only heap changes bigger and bigger every time. About 90M after 1000 time call dlopen & dlclose to me 90M is still too big.

```
026fb000-0274e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

after googled about 2 weeks but nothing helpful for this issue. Only find a document said as below [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gcc/).

> **-fno-gnu-unique** 
>   On systems with recent GNU assembler and C library, the C++ compiler uses the "STB_GNU_UNIQUE" binding to make sure that
>   definitions of template static data members and static local variables
>   in inline functions are unique even in the presence of "RTLD_LOCAL";
>   this is necessary to avoid problems with a library used by two
>   different "RTLD_LOCAL" plugins depending on a definition in one of
>   them and therefore disagreeing with the other one about the binding of
>   the symbol. But this causes "dlclose" to be ignored for affected DSOs;
>   if your program relies on reinitialization of a DSO via "dlclose" and
>   "dlopen", you can use -fno-gnu-unique.

Is this a linux bug? Is there anyone can help me on this issue? thanks.
The environment is gcc 5.3.1. I linked with definitions _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI.

Comment: Is anyone can help me on this issue?

Comment: `--no-gnu-unique` et. al. must be used on the DSO which is being loaded, at the cost of violating some C++ guarantees, which are implemented with STB_GNU_UNIQUE typed symbols.